# Issue- Getting excel file from sharepoint using python

Tags: python, excel, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

Error is coming while i am trying to get files from sharepoint using following python code. Here is the error msg : **An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS53003: Access has been blocked by Conditional Access policies. The access policy does not allow token issuance**. Could anyone help me how to do that? Here is my code:

```
import os
import shutil
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
sharepoint_url = "Sharepoint_site_url"
site_url = "site url"
username = "My_username"
password = "Password"
# File path components
library_name = "Shared Documents"
folder_name = "ABCD"
# Construct the full file path
file_path = f"https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/{library_name}/{folder_name}/"
# Encode the file path
encoded_file_path = file_path.replace(" ", "%20")  # Replace spaces with %20
print(encoded_file_path)
# Authenticate with SharePoint
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(sharepoint_url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    # Connect to SharePoint site
    ctx = ClientContext(site_url, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
 
    # Get all files in the SharePoint folder
    files = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_path(file_path).files
    ctx.load(files)
    ctx.execute_query()
    # Create a folder on the C drive
    c_drive_folder1 = "C:/ENTERP/Raw"
    c_drive_folder2 = "C:/ENTERPR/Processed"
    os.makedirs(c_drive_folder1, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(c_drive_folder2, exist_ok=True)
    # Download and save each file to the C drive folder
for file in files:
        print(1)
        file_name = file.properties["Name"]
        file_url = f"{site_url}/{library_name}/{folder_name}/{file_name}"
        file_content = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_path(file_url).read().execute_query()
        # Save the file to the C drive folder
        file_path_on_c_drive = os.path.join(c_drive_folder1, file_name)
        with open(file_path_on_c_drive, "wb") as local_file:
            local_file.write(file_content)
        print(f"Downloaded and saved: {file_name} to {file_path_on_c_drive}")
        print("Download process completed.")
else:
        print("Failed to authenticate with SharePoint.")
```

Any alternate solution suggestion would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

AAD blocks token acquisition because username and password authentication is deprecated in favour of app based authentication. You need to create an "app only" App Registration in Azure that is granted SPO API access (SharePoint > Sites.Selected), and then the app needs "read" access on the site ([ref](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/develop-applications-that-use-sites-selected-permissions-for-spo/ba-p/3790476)). You'll then need to auth like [this](https://waragorn-boonpanya.medium.com/connecting-to-sharepoint-with-python-using-service-principal-663b4a34aaca).
Alternatively, if you are in full control of your environment you could grant the app registration access to all sites (SharePoint > Sites.FullControl.All).

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?